# gtsummary - excluding columns when using "by"

Tags: r, gtsummary

In the following code, gtsummary creates a table having 8 columns - one for each possible value of career_stage_s1_v2.

I am trying to limit the output so that gtsummary only displays only 2 of the possible 8 columns - I do not want to see the 6/8 columns where the filter has reduced the total number of observations to 0.

Here is the code. How do I display only the 2 columns of the variable I am targeting with my filter (career_stage_s1_v2 = "Student", career_stage_s1_v2 = "Currently practicing")?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
table10 <- select(df, career_stage_s1_v2, mhcsf_emotional_wb, mhcsf_social_wb, mhcsf_psychological_wb) %>%
filter(career_stage_s1_v2 %in% c("Student", "Currently practicing") & (mhcsf_emotional_wb != "Incomplete" | mhcsf_social_wb != "Incomplete" | mhcsf_psychological_wb != "Incomplete")) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = career_stage_s1_v2,
    label = list(career_stage_s1_v2 ~ "Student, Currently practicing"),
    sort = all_categorical() ~ "frequency"
  ) %>%
  modify_caption("**Well Being - emotional, social, or psychological well-being domains by career stage**") %>%
  bold_labels()
table10
```

Comment: Is your by variable a factor? In that case, gtsummary will show all levels of a factor, even if they are not observed in your data. If that's the case, you can keep your filter and then convert your by variable to character.

Comment: Thanks @DanielD.Sjoberg. It worked, but I also had to remove the line using the label command.